# Nested loop, inner loop is not iterating the values from the outer loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files: a YAML file and a TXT file. I want to append some of their values in specific order. So far I've made most of the work, but I can't understand the following:
 From the YAML I'm retrieving values under variable named "flavor" which values I need to check if appear line by line in the TXT file. When I execute the code below and print "flavor" in the nested loop I can see the same value multiple times, but if I print it in the outer loop, the values are fine. How can I achieve the same result in the nested loop ? It's very important to append the values in the order like it is now.

```
 for count in yml['vm_types']:
    whole_list = []
    name = count['name']
    whole_list.append(name)
    disk_size = count['cloud_properties']['root_disk']['size']
    whole_list.append(disk_size)
    flavor = count['cloud_properties']['instance_type']
    whole_list.append(flavor)
    for line in os_flavors:
      print(flavor)
      if re.search(flavor, line):
        fields = line.strip().split()
        ram = fields[5]
        whole_list.append(ram)
        vcpu = fields[11]
        whole_list.append(vcpu)
```

Comment: Where is ```os_flavors``` is defined in your code?

Comment: os_flavors is the variable which reads the TXT file